# RxJava subscription to side effect

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, side-effects

I have a question, it is simple business logic flow:

check whether an employee in multiple departments, department and employee relationship is in cache, first check whether the relationships exists in cache, if exist, check whether
employee belong it, in case of not in cache, get it from database, and check the relationship about the employee and then save the department info to cache.

this is the code:

```
public Observable  isEmployeeInDepartment(List<Long> departmentIds, long employeeId){

     //this observable will resolve twice, and cause unnecessary cache access
     Observable  departmentInfoExsitInCache= checkDepartmentInfoFromCache(...).share();   

     Observable  departInfoNotInCache = departmentInfoExsitInCache.filter(...);

     //this observable will resolve twice, and cause unnecessary database access
     Observable  departmentInfoFromDb=departInfoNotInCache.flatMap(departmentIds->checkFromDb()).share(); 

     Observable<Long> saveResult=departmentInfoFromDb.flatMap(departmentInfo->saveToCache());

     Observable<Long> departInfoInCache = departmentInfoExsitInCache.filter(...);

     return departInfoInCache.check(userId).merge( departmentInfoFromDb.check(userId)).doOnCompleted(saveResult.subscribe());
}
```

the problem is that departmentInfoExsitInCache and saveResult will be resolved twice by once client method subscribe.

I found that once remove the save subscription code .doOnCompleted(saveResult.subscribe()), it will become normal and only resolve once. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing share here.
The issue is that `share()` will not help you in this case. `share()` is actually `publish().autoConnect()` meant to keep single subscription to a stream, thus calling again subscribe will not invoke the subscription logic again but will just connect you to an existing stream.
**But**, after all subscribers unsubscribed from a shared stream, the Observable will unsubsscribe, That means when you call again `subscribe()`, you will invoke the subscription logic and call to DB/Cache again.

So, what you're doing is subscribing again to shared operator after it unsubscribed. ( in the `doOnCompleted()`), that will cause the `departmentInfoFromDb` and `departmentInfoExsitInCache` to subscribe again and go to DB/Cache.

Consider using `cache()/reply()` operator for persisting the fetched value from DB/Cache between subscription.

Comment: in fact, I don't know any method to make ```saveResult``` to be resolved when the whole method's returned observable get subscripted, except put it in the "main" returned observable's ```doOnCompleted()``` method to make it subscripted as well

Comment: if you want the `saveResult` to be subscribed after the merged `Obesrvable` in the last line, you can use `concat()` operator. but anyhow it will not solve this issue